# cómo mapear un model a viewmodel mvc

Tags: mvc, viewmodel

Tengo un objeto Usuarios que tiene un método obtener que retorna una lista, y tengo un objeto `UsuariosViewModel` que tiene las mismas propiedades que el objeto Usuario, cómo puedo mapear lo que me regresa el método obtener al objeto viewmodel?; ocupo mandar el objeto `viewmodel` ya que en la vista regreso el viewmodel.

```
public ActionResult About()
{
    List<tblUsuarios> usuarios= new tblUsuarios().Obtener();
    List<tblUsuariosViewModel> usuarios = new List<tblUsuariosViewModel>();
    return View(usuarios);
}
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Hola, te invito a leer [ask] y [mcve]. Por favor, agrega el código en formato texto, no en imagenes. Es necesario que indiques el error o dificultad encontrada y el resultado esperado. Si crees que puedes mejorar tu pregunta haz clic en [edit]. De lo contrario es posible que la misma termine cerrada. Saludos

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes hacer algo como esto:

```
List<tblUsuariosViewModel> usuarios = _usuarios.Select(x => new tblUsuariosViewModel() { 
 Propiedad1 = x.Propiedad1,
 Propiedad2 = x.Propiedad2
}).ToList();
```

También puedes usar [AutoMapper](http://automapper.org/), aquí tienes un [ejemplo](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper).

Comment: Funcionó, muchas gracias :)... si había visto automapper, pero quería logragrlo sin eso.